# What are the Item restrictions during VS races?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

In Mario Kart Wii, certain items have restrictions for when or under what condition they may be gotten. By this, I do not mean the items based on placement system.

Some Items can be pulled only after a certain time limit. For example, the Shock can be used only once in 30 seconds. I know there are other items that have similar use restrictions, but what are these items, and what restriction do they have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a slightly more complete answer.

| Item | Max in play | Time before 1st item | Cooldown after use | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lightning | 1 | 00:30 | 00:30 | - |
| POW Block | 1 | 00:20 | 00:20 | - |
| Blooper | 1 | 00:15 | 00:15 | - |
| Spiny Shell | 1 | 00:30 | 00:00 | Unused code exists for a 30 sec cooldown |
| Bullet Bill | 1 | 00:00 | 00:00 | - |
| Thundercloud | 1 | 00:00 | 00:00 | Cannot pull Thundercloud while any player has thundercloud above them<sup>[3](https://wiki.tockdom.com/wiki/Item_Settings_-_Item_Boxes#Rules)</sup> |
| Mega Mushroom | 2 | 00:00 | 00:00 | Cannot pull Mega Mushroom while mega<sup>[3](https://wiki.tockdom.com/wiki/Item_Settings_-_Item_Boxes#Rules)</sup> |
| Golden Mushroom | 2 | 00:00 | 00:00 | - |
| Star | 3 | 00:00 | 00:00 | - |
| Bob-omb | 3 | 00:00 | 00:00 | - |
| (Triple) Mushroom | 12 | 00:00 | 00:00 | Bypasses limit in some circumstances (see below) |
| Fake Item Box | 6 | 00:00 | 00:00 | - |
| (Triple) Banana | 16 | 00:00 | 00:00 | Cannot pull triple bananas while trailing<sup>[3](https://wiki.tockdom.com/wiki/Item_Settings_-_Item_Boxes#Rules)</sup>. |
| (Triple) Red Shell | 8 | 00:00 | 00:00 | Cannot pull triple red shells while circling<sup>[3](https://wiki.tockdom.com/wiki/Item_Settings_-_Item_Boxes#Rules)</sup>. |
| (Triple) Green Shell | 12 | 00:00 | 00:00 | Cannot pull triple green shells while circling<sup>[3](https://wiki.tockdom.com/wiki/Item_Settings_-_Item_Boxes#Rules)</sup>. |

[Here's the source for this data](https://xer.forgotten-legends.org/re/mkw/items/), with some extra notes.

The "max in play" includes dropped, circling, trailing, and held items (but if you roll a dropped item, the dropped item will go poof (or 3 in the case of triples)). Note that having a star or mega mushroom active does not count against the item limit (the bullet bill does however).

When you hit an item box, you check which items others have and will adjust your probabilities accordingly (for example if you're in 12th but there is a bullet bill, 3 stars, and 2 golden mushrooms in play, your chance of pulling lightning becomes 80%<sup>[2](https://youtu.be/r0Gei2Mbm-g?si=-F6m02kb1hGVxs1Q&t=370)</sup>).

However, say you hit the item box at the same time as someone else and you both roll stars but there's already 2 in play, one player will get a single mushroom instead, **ignoring the item limit**.

(This does not apply to triple mushrooms, which **ignores the item limit** if there's a conflict and still gives both players triple mushrooms.<sup>[4](https://mariokartwii.com/showthread.php?tid=111&pid=6383#pid6383)</sup>)

In addition, the 16th, 18th, 20th (and further) items you pull will always be single mushrooms, **ignoring the item limit**.

Comment: I had no idea that there's a limit on every item! Great answer and thanks for providing the source!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about other items with time restrictions. But I do know that some items are restricted to only one existing in a race at a time.

For example, only 1 blue shell can exist at any one time.
So if someone gets a blue shell from an item box, they could hold onto it the whole race, and no one would ever get a blue shell.

I believe Bullet Bill follows this rule too.
There's a good chance that there's a "cooldown" for bloopers/POW blocks too, as you never really see two of them at the same time, and they also hit multiple players at once.